# How to make a treeview from XSD file?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, treeview

I have a problem with displayed my XSD file in treeview control in C#. I wonder what is the simplest way to do it. Can I read the XSD file like, a normal XML ? How can I recognize the attribute and get the value of "ref"?
This is my XSD file:

```
<xs:element name="Document-ProductCatalogue">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="ProductCatalogue-Header">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="ProductCatalogue-Parties">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" ref="ProductCatalogue-Groups">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="ProductCatalogue-Groups">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="Group">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

I'd like to get a tree view which looks like this:

```
Document-ProductCatalogue
   ProductCatalogue-Header
   ProductCatalogue-Parties
   ProductCatalogue-Groups
ProductCatalogue-Groups
   Group
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, please show your code and explain its problems. If not, please explain why.

Comment: Look into `XDocument` and its friends.

Comment: This article on [populating a treeview with xml data](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317597) might help.